# Python Dictionary How to call first Element in for loop

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been trying to display the p_record output.

My Question is How do I call the first Element from p_record in FOR LOOP?
The program should call the next player but ended up giving me the same last player.

def main():

```
attempts = 0
white = 0
wrong = 0
black = 0 
game = True    
p_record = {}
whiteblack = []
score = 0
black = 0
scorenum = 0
count = 0
temp = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
NoOfWins = 0
winlose = ""
hiddencodeExample = ['B', 'P', 'G', 'Y']
player_guess = []
colors = ['B', 'R', 'Y', 'O', 'G', 'P']
color_code = random.sample(colors, 4)         
print ("HIDDEN CODE", hiddencodeExample)
num = int(input('Please enter number of players: '))
for i in range(num):
         names = str(input('Please enter a name: '))
         #p_record[] = names
         p_record = {names: {"Score":scorenum, winlose: NoOfWins}}
         #p_record["Score"].append(scorenum) 
         print(p_record)
         #p_record.append([names, scorenum, 0])
         # print(p_record[0])
         # print(scorenum)
         # print(p_record[1])
         # print(p_record)
         # print(names)
while game:  # for x in range(0, num)
         for player in list(p_record):
         #for player in p_record.keys():
                  print(player, ",", "make a guess of 4 colors from RGBYOP: ")          
                  player_input_guess = input("").upper()
                  player_guess = player_input_guess
                  # print(p_record[0], p_record[1])
                  # print(player_guess[0])
                  # score1 = ''.join(score)
                  # score.append(scorenum)
                  # print(score)
                  whiteblack.clear()
                  print("Current player:", player, "Current Score:", p_record.get(scorenum))
                  for i in range(len(player_guess)):  # BORY
                           # print(i)
                           if(player_guess[i] == hiddencodeExample[i]):  # iterate every character and check if tally
                                    # print("position no",i, player_guess[i])
                                    black += 1
                                    scorenum += 5
                                    whiteblack.append("B")
                                    # p_record.insert(1, scorenum)
                                    #player[1] += 5


                                    p_record.update({"Score": 5})
                                    # print(player[1])

                           elif player_guess[i] != hiddencodeExample[i] and player_guess[i] in hiddencodeExample:  # 
                                    # print("2position no", i, player_guess[i])
                                    white += 1 
                                    scorenum += 1
                                    whiteblack.append("W")
                                    #player[1] += 1
                                    #p_record["Score"] += 1
                                    p_record.update({"Score": 1})
                                    # print(player[1])
                                    # p_record.insert(1, scorenum)

                           else:
                                    whiteblack.append("")  

                  print(whiteblack)
                  print(p_record)
                  color_codeString = ''.join(hiddencodeExample)                    
                  print("Current player:", player, "Updated Score:", p_record.get(scorenum))
                  # whiteblack.reverse()
                  # print(whiteblack.reverse())  
                  whiteblackString = ''.join(whiteblack)

                  print("Result", whiteblackString)

                  if(player_guess == color_codeString):
                           game = False
                           print("Correct Guess!")
                           print("Winner: ", p_record)
                           print("<ENTER> to play and any letter to stop:  ")
                          # if keyboard.is_pressed('ENTER'):
                          #          game = True
                          # else:
                          #          game = False
```

main()

But the display shows (Two players playing) David and Ben:

David, make a guess of 4 colors from RGBYOP:
//next player

David, make a guess of 4 colors from RGBYOP:
//next player

Score, make a guess of 4 colors from RGBYOP:
//next player

David, make a guess of 4 colors from RGBYOP:

What I wanted is for two players playing:

David, make a guess of 4 colors from RGBYOP: //next player

Ben, make a guess of 4 colors from RGBYOP: //next player

Comment: This code you've posted won't run.  The indentation is screwed up, part of the code is miscapitalised, and you are using variables that are not declared in your code. Please post runnable code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have edited and put the full code.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you post a [mcve]. What you have posted is not *minimal*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the contents of the p_record object in every loop when you say.

```
p_record = {names: {"Score":scorenum, winlose: NoOfWins}}
```

p_record is therefore either Ben or David. To fix this, you should probably restructure the object. Try using:

```
p_record[names] = {"Score":scorenum, winlose: NoOfWins}
```

and re-structure around that.
This would make p_record look like:

```
{'David': {'Score': 0, '': 0}, 'Ben': {'Score': 0, '': 0}}
```

You can then access David's score with p_record["David"]["Score"], for example

Hope this helps!

**NOTE:** By simply changing "p_record =" to "p_record[names] =" the code *nearly* works (as in: it alternates as you want it to, but the rest of the game doesn't work properly), but you should clean it up as suggested above since there is no need to store names twice.

Also you should try using an IDE which permits run-time object inspection and breakpoints. It's much easier to see why it's not working like this.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Yes, my codes are quite messy atm.

Comment: @Atrix370 No worries, let me know if you need anymore help with this ^

Comment: I tried to show the score with p_record["David"].Score but it doesn't work as AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Score'

Comment: I just found out I can change the score using p_record[player]["Score"] = 1. Thanks!

Comment: Yep! Sorry about that. I've been doing too much JavaScript recently (in which either method works) :) Was going to message when I got home (now), but glad you've figured it out

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the rest of the code implementation, but it seems like you are iterating over every element in the dictionary, when instead you just want its entries.

```
for player in list(p_record)
```

should be replaced for

```
for player in p_record.entries()
```

Maybe there's your problem.

Comment: I have edited the code using p_record.entries() but it gave me an error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'entries'